# If Cell Contains Value, Color Entire Row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to color the entire row of any cell that contains "C" within a particular column. there also exist "P"'s that I do not want to color. Here is my code.

```
Sub color()
Dim lastRow As Long

With Sheets("MP Parameters")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("K5:K" & lastRow)
        .Value = IIf(Interior.ColorIndex = 15, "C", "P")
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

I get an object error on the `.Value = IIf(Interior.ColorIndex = 15, "C", "P")`

Comment: You dropped a period `.Value = IIf(.Interior.ColorIndex = 15, "C", "P")` so Interior wasn't referring to the Range.Interior

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting?

Comment: While that explains your error, it doesn't fix your code, which wouldn't do anything near what you described. Conditional formatting would indeed be best for that. If you don't want to use it for some reason, it'll take a significant code rewrite to do what you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that if the cell contains a "C" and doesn't contain a "P" then color it.

Examples

- "ABCDEF" : Color it
- "ABCP" : Do not color it
- "ABC" : Color it
- "DEFGH" : Do not color it

---

```
Sub color()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim x As Long

    With Sheets("MP Parameters")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 5 To lastRow

            If .Cells(x, "K") Like "*C*" And Not .Cells(x, "K") Like "*P*" Then

                .Rows(x).Interior.ColorIndex = 15

            End If

        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is much better. Thank you. I'm often confusing functions in VBA. I think i just need more experience in general. I appreciate it!

Comment: I recommend watching all the [VBA WiseOwlTutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) on Youtube.